# Get count of rows limit value sql php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cumulative-sum

I have an sql table trade with following data

```
  id| value
   1| 0.1
   2| 0.5
   3| 0.9
   4| 0.3
```

How do I make an SQL query so that i get the count of entries limited to total value of 0.8 ascending by id in php.
For example:-

```
COUNT id FROM trade WHERE SUM(value) > 0.8 by id ASC
```

Result should come as

```
 3
```

Comment: please edit you question and provide information what do you expect  as result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do cumulative judgment,due to your mysql version didn't support window function so the solution will be a little hard to read,becuase you need to write subquery instead of window function.

make the cumulative number by `Id` column, then get the `MIN(ID)` in subquery, when `Id = 3` the value will greater than `0.8`.

finally get the Id small and equal the `MIN(ID)` you will get your expect result.

```
CREATE TABLE trade(
   id  INT,
    value FLOAT
);

INSERT INTO trade VALUES(1,0.1);
INSERT INTO trade VALUES(2,0.5);
INSERT INTO trade VALUES(3,0.9);
INSERT INTO trade VALUES(4,0.3);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM trade t1
WHERE t1.id <= (
SELECT MIN(ID) FROM (
 SELECT ID,(
    SELECT SUM(tt.value) 
    FROM trade tt
    WHERE tt.id <= t1.id  
  ) total
  FROM trade t1
) t1
where total > 0.8
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29ae6/33/0)**:

```
| COUNT(*) |
|----------|
|        3 |
```

Comment: Its returning 2 ...i want 3. For example the first three ids sum up to 1.5 . So 0.8 < 1.5 ...it should return first 3 id

Comment: @JeffB Ok I see Wait a second

Comment: @JeffB What's your mysql version?

Comment: Server version: 5.7.23 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: #1046 - No database selected

Comment: Is there a way I can get the ids of those as well?

Comment: Thanks appreciate u alot :D

Comment: How do I only get the last Id?

Comment: And everything except last id?

Comment: Can you please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52236678/select-count-of-rows-in-mysqli

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you need aggregate function and cumulative sum need to filter your desired result

```
 set @csum := 0.0;
select count(id) from
(

select id,@csum := @csum + value as sum_val   from t 
 order by id
 ) t1
where  sum_val <1.3
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/abf460/2

```
count(id)
 3
```

Comment: i do not understand. the id is always unique, so group by id is unnecessary

Comment: @hotfix it seems to me op has multiple  value for single user but yes your point is valid but from his query try i guess that

Comment: I wanted count not select id

Comment: @JeffB then use simple count and where clause

Comment: Its returning 2 on my side

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179306/discussion-between-jeffb-and-zaynul-abadin-tuhin).

Comment: @JeffB if it help please accept answer as SO appreciation

Comment: Wait when i try select count(id) from trade where amount <1.3, its returning 4 which is wrong. It should return 3. i want it to check ascending order id sum

Comment: @JeffB could you give sample of your real data cause i have not found 1.3 in sample data

Comment: @JeffB all the values are below 1.3 so it returns 4 how it will return 3 ??

Comment: U didnt understand the question...it should add all the values by id ascending so first 3 add up as 1.5. So i want a query in which it returns count of entries by ascending order where limit sum 1.3. Meaning result should come as 3 as 1.3<1.5 of first three entries

Comment: returning me as 2

Comment: In my database it is returning 2 idk why

Comment: I know but idk why not for my sql .... Anyways the answer above urs works just fine